# network traffic packet enumeration with tshark

Tags: networking, wireshark, pcap, tshark

Although it sounds easy, I cannot find an answer around..

I just need to enumerate certain packets in a certain pcap file (with tshark).
e.g.: 
how many packets are ipv6.ack?
how many packets are udp?

and tshark has to print just a number...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-z io,stat,0` option, e.g.:

```
tshark -r capture.pcap -q -z io,stat,0,"udp"
```

... however this will produce an IO Statistics table, not a single number.

If you have tools like `wc`, `grep` and `cut` available to you, you could try one or more of these solutions:

```
tshark -r capture.pcap -q -z io,stat,0,"udp" | grep "<>" | cut -d ' ' -f 8
tshark -r capture.pcap -Y "udp" | wc -l
```

If you're on Windows, and you don't have any of these tools, you could try wrapping this in a batch file, such as:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

IF "%1" == "" GOTO :USAGE
IF "%2" == "" (
    SET TSHARK_CMD=tshark.exe -r %1 -z io,stat,0
) ELSE (
    SET TSHARK_CMD=tshark.exe -r %1 -z io,stat,0,"%2"
)

FOR /F "TOKENS=6 DELIMS= " %%A in ('!TSHARK_CMD! ^| FINDSTR "^<^>"') DO (
    ECHO %%A
)
GOTO :END

:USAGE
ECHO usage: printframes ^<file^> ^[filter^]

ENDLOCAL
:END
```